# Why doesn't my Analog output work on Radeon R9 280x?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, vga, dvi, amd-radeon

I have a Asus R9 Radeon 280x.
The outputs work fine with digital devices, ie those that use DVI or HDMI.
It has one DVI-I dual link which is supposed to work with Analog sources like VGA (with an adapter of course). 
I remember it working before but dear I say it does not now.

The computer detects the VGA display. The OS responds by switching to a dual monitor layout. I can see this and confirm it in display properties. However there is no video. The monitor just says no signal if I turn it off and on again.

The problem is OS independent since the same thing happens during Post. The screen remains blank and I cannot see the prompt to enter the BIOS let alone enter it.

I have tried BIOS updates for the system as well as the GPU. I have tried using the the same DVI-I port with a digital display with no problem.
I have also tried various driver versions.

I would like this to work since I have a somewhat unique setup. I have been getting by by using a second GPU for my primary display.